# Failed to save state in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I cannot restore the scroll position of horizontal RecyclerView when I go back to this fragment from another fragment. So I have one main vertical RecyclerView that has several horizontal RecyclerViews in it. And I need to save the position of these inner lists. Here is my Fragment, where I save state:

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (outState == null){
            outState = new Bundle();
        }
        // saves the positions in lists
        Map<String, Parcelable> states = mainVideoAdapter.saveSubListState();
        Iterator it = states.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            outState.putParcelable((String) pair.getKey(), (Parcelable) pair.getValue());

        }

    }
```

Here is the code where I call `onSaveInstanceState()` (adapter):

```
Map<String, Parcelable> states;
    public Map<String, Parcelable> saveSubListState(){
        states = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mainItems.size(); i++) {
            if (!mainItems.get(i).isSliding()){
                String key = mainItems.get(i).getGenreEntity().getId();
                if (recyclerViews.get(key) != null){
                    states.put(key, recyclerViews.get(key).getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState());
                }
            }
        }

        return states;
    }
```

And here I retrieve this state in Fragment:

```
Bundle outState;
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (outState != null){
            Map<String, Parcelable> states = mainVideoAdapter.getStates();
            if (states != null && !states.isEmpty()){
                Iterator it = states.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    Parcelable savedRecyclerLayoutState = outState.getParcelable((String) pair.getKey());
                    mainVideoAdapter.getRecyclerViews().get(pair.getKey())
                            .getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(savedRecyclerLayoutState);
                    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                }
            }
        }    

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do like this in fragment where your `Recyclerview`is placed.

```
View mView; // declare it globally

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       if(mView == null){ // it will not reload Recyclerview it will set first time view which is loaded. 
          mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourview, null);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

> Fragment `onCreateView()` call each time when navigate back to that fragment. so initialize `View` for the first time, This `Recyclerview` state will remain as it is.

Hope this help

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help

Comment: Did you remove other code ? from `onResume()` and `OnPause()` ? where you did save changes stuff?  need to comment or remove that code.

Comment: Yes. I actually tried both variants: with my code and without it.

Comment: So what happen when you have done it without code ?  does it reload it each time ?

Comment: If I remove my code and put yours only it even doesn't restore the state after Activity is gone. With my code it restore the scroll position after Activity in Fragment but not after Fragment in Fragment. I edited my question to show what I have in onCreateView()

Comment: Sorry, my fault. In onCreateView() I set the adapter again. But I need to also keep my code, since if I return from Activity it won't keep the state.